# Visual Studio Web Project Statistics

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, webforms, statistics

I'm looking for something that can spit out statistics on Visual Studio 2008 web projects, both Forms and MVC.

Things like:

- Number of pages per project
- Number of user controls
- Number of classes
- Number of methods
- Number of images/CSS
- File creation dates

If the information exists already in Visual Studio, I can't find it. I've also tried [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Stats.aspx), but it only offers your basic lines-of-code type stats, which I find nearly worthless on web-based projects. Any suggestions? I'll write something if necessary, but I'd rather just use an existing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can do all this and much more. VS Team System gives you code metrics, but it's much less flexible than NDepend.

**Update** I just posted [a lengthy review of NDepend](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/24/38398/).